# Boundary of manifold with boundary

Tags: differential-forms, stokes-theorem, manifolds-with-boundary

### Boundary of a *surface-with-boundary*

I'm reading "Advanced calculus: a differential forms approach".

Author defines $S$, a *compact, oriented, differentiable surface-with-boundary* in $xyz$-space by describing a finite number of oriented charts $F_i$, of the $uv$-plane to $xyz$-plane. In particular,

(a) A finite number of differentiable maps ("charts") $F_1, F_2, ..., F_N$ of the $uv$-plane to the $xyz$-space are given. Each $F_i$ is one-to-one and non-singular of rank 2 on the square  $ \{|u|≤ 1, |v|≤1\}.$

(b) For each $F_i$ there is specified a closed rectactangle in $ \{|u|≤ 1, |v|≤1\}$ , such that the image of a point of the square under $F_i$ is a point of $S$ if and only if the point lies in $R_i$.

(c) For each $P$ in $S$ there is an $i, 1≤ i ≤ N $, and an $\epsilon>0$, such that $P=F_i(u, v)$ where $|u|<1, |v|<1$, and such that a point $Q$ in the $xyz$-space which lies within $\epsilon$ of $P$ lies in $S$ if and only if it lies in $F_i(R_i)$

(d) the orientations of the charts agree.

It is then defined the boundary of $S$, $\partial S$, as

> Those points of $S$ which are the image under some $F_i$ of a point inside $ \{|u|≤ 1, |v|≤1\}$  which lies on a boundary of $R_i$.

---

How is this possible? Why a point on a boundary of $R_i$, under $F_i$, is a point in $\partial S$?

---

### Boundary of a sphere, according to this definition

To visualize the definition, I tried to apply it to a sphere, to see what would happen.

Let's consider S as the unit sphere centered at the origin, i.e.

$S=\{(x,y,z)∈\mathbb{R}^3∣x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$

We can choose, using the streographic projections of the sphere minus the north (or south) pole, and by introducing a scale factor, $F_1, F_2$ so that they parametrize the square one-to-one into an entire hemisphere. Hence, $R_1=R_2=\{|u|≤ 1, |v|≤1\}.$
(Of course we have also to make sure that these charts are consistently oriented).

But then, by definition, the boundary of S, $\partial S$, is

$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{2} F_{i}(\partial R_i)$;

i.e. the equator of the sphere. But this is of course false, the (manifold's) boundary of a sphere is the empty set.
What if we were to define the charts such that they parametrize all but a small area around the omitted pole? The boundary of the sphere would change (hence this definition is not well-defined); and then would the Stokes's Theorem hold?

---

Screenshots of the pages I'm talking about:

[Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldk7T.png)

[Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGIQ7.png)

Comment: I think your problem is that you are misquoting the textbook definition of a surface and of it's boundary.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Hopefully so; I have just now attached to the question two screenshots of the pages. If you could make me understand what I'm misquoting, it would be very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: @MoisheKohan Hello, here they are the definitions of the textbook:  [definition of a surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldk7T.png), [definition of its boundary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGIQ7.png). I'd be thankful if you could explain what I misquoted and why this definition works!

Comment: Sorry, my apologies, you are quoting correctly, the fault is with the textbook's author. How did he manage to mishandle one of the most basic definitions in differential topology, and how did the referees of the book missed this, is beyond me. Consider reading a different book on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the author managed to give a wrong definition of a surface with boundary. After a bit of thought, item (c) in the definition implies that each (closed rectangle) $R_i$ is contained in the  interior of the square $[-1,1]^2$. From this, it follows (again using item (c)) that the images of the rectangles $R_i$ under  the maps $F_i$ are pairwise disjoint in $S$. Thus, what the author of the book "defined" is not a surface with boundary but a surface with corners. Moreover, only few surfaces with corners satisfy this definition (only those which are diffeomorphic to the disjoint union of finitely many closed rectangles), for instance, $S^2$, $T^2$, etc., do not.

There are many sources where surfaces (and, more generally, manifolds) with boundary are defined properly. For instance, consider reading the book by Guillemin and Pollack "Differential Topology."

Comment: Thank you for your answers and for your suggestion. But why the images of the rectagles $R_i$ under the maps $F_i$ are pairwaise disjoint in $S$? Item (c) only says that there is at least one chart $F_i$. Furthermore, it is said in page 202 that "The main reason that decomposing $\omega$ [differential form over the manifold] is simpler than decomposing $S$, is that the parametrized portions may now overlap and in fact should overlap in such a way that every point of $S$ is inside one parametrized portion". Also, would the Stokes' Theorem be valid in this "surface-with-corners"?

Comment: Part (c) itself has two parts. The second part of (c) implies that for every $P\in F_i(R_i)$, if $P_k\in S$ is a sequence converging to $P$, then for all sufficiently large $k$, $P_k$ belongs to $F_i(R_i)$. Hence,  $F_i(R_i)$ is open in $S$ in the subspace topology. From this, it also follows that for any other $j$, if $F_j(R_j)\cap F_i(R_i)\ne \emptyset$, then $F_j(R_j)\subset F_i(R_i)$. reversing the roles of $i$ and $j$, we get $F_j(R_j)= F_i(R_i)$ in this setting. What he says elsewhere in the book does not matter.

Comment: As for Stokes' theorem: It does hold for surfaces with corners.

Comment: Wait, but if $F_i(R_i)$ is open in $S$ in the subspace topology, and $F_j(R_j)∩F_i(R_i)≠∅$ iff $F_j(R_j)=Fi(Ri)$ then there are points $P$ which don't belong to any $F_i(R_i)$, namely the points $P$ on the boundary of some $F_i(R_i)$, in contradiction with (c). Am I missing something?

Comment: Unless of course $S$ is not connected. (because it is the union of two or more pairwise disjoint non-empty open subsets, i.e. the $F_i(R_i), 0≤i≤N$ ), but I don't think this is the case.

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote: With the given "definition" the only surfaces are disjoint unions of rectangles (up to a diffeomorphism). This is why the given "definition" is utter nonsense.

Comment: I see, I see, thank you!

Comment: Just one more thing, if there is an $F_i$ (for which (c) does not hold) only such that $P∈F_i(R_i)$, then can there be another $F_j$ such that both parts of (c) hold?

Comment: Would not this invalidate the claim that for every $P∈F_i(R_i)...$ since it's actually for every $P$ which lies in both $F_i(R_i)$ and $F_j(R_j)$. (So that it isn't a problem if $P∈∂F_i(R_i)$ because $P∈F_j(R_j)/{∂F_j(R_j)}$) Though the definition is still full of problems and probably I'll read  "Differential Topology.". I'm sorry to bother you.

Comment: @Mr.Verres I do not understand your question, I explained what is wrong with the given definition. Are you proposing a modification of their definition?

Comment: I understood all your explanation of what's wrong with the given definition, except the premise, i.e.: "The second part of (c) implies that for every $P∈F_i(R_i)$, if $P_k∈S$ is a sequence converging to $P$, then for all sufficiently large $k$, $P_k$ belongs to $F_i(R_i)$." Wouldn't it actually be "For every $P∈S$, which lies inside  $F_i(R_i)$ and possibly in others  $F_j(R_j)$"? (c) only says that "there is at least a $F_i$ for each $P$ such that (...)"; so that it is possible that $P∈F_i(R_i)$ (c does not hold for $F_i$ and $P$) but $P∈F_j(R_j)$ (c holds  $F_j$ and $P$).

Comment: -Though the definition is trash anyway-

Comment: @Mr.Verres: I see, I was misreading Part (c). Then, indeed, every surface with boundary (in the usual sense) admits such a system of maps of rectangles. However, then, the definition of the boundary is wrong as it does not agree with the usual one. For instance, if $S$ is the union of two rectangles, $R_1=[-0.9,0.9]^2, R_2=[-0.8, 0.8]^2$, with the identity maps $F_1, F_2$. Then, according to the given definition, the boundary of $S$ is the union of boundaries of the two rectangles and not the boundary of $R_1$, as it would be in the case of a manifold with corners.

Comment: Exactly! Thank you so much!

Comment: By the way does the Stokes Theorem hold with this "definition" of boundary and manifold with boundary (though it does not define a general manifold with boundary)?

Comment: No, it will fail with this "definition" of the boundary.